# Как стилизовать стрелку в select

Tags: сss3

У меня есть select и стрелка для выпадающего списка стандартного стиля. Как я могу её стилизовать под свой дизайн? По сути мне нужно сделать белый фон, убрать рамку и задать border-radius. Сама стрелка подходит. 
[image: Текущий стиль]

[image: Как нужно]

Comment: Нельзя стилизовать. Можно её убрать и добавить фоном свою

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему, для этого надо делать полностью кастомный UI для Select. Можете взять за основу Input и выводить список при клике по стрелке или телу блока.

Более простой вариант - скрыть стрелку и добавить фоном собственное изображение, но это надо проверять во всех браузерах. Некоторые могут некорректно отображать подобные изменения.

> Сама стрелка подходит.

Имейте ввиду, что в разных браузерах дефолтная стрелка будет отображаться по разному, в зависимости от браузерного движка.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно прибегнуть к jquery UI вот здесь подробнее http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

```js
$('select').selectmenu()
```

```css
.ui-selectmenu-text {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
  <option>dolor</option>
</select>
```